# Export django model to database adding extra fields

Tags: python-3.x, django, metaprogramming

For exportation into a dbdump, I need to create a table that is a exact clone of my model but with a "summary" column.

Given that the model is concrete, not abstract, to subclass it is a failure, as

```
class AnnotatedModel(MyModel):
    summary = m.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

creates a new table with only the new field.

I have attempted to use metaclass inheritance instead, but I am stuck because of the `model.Meta` subclass of Django `BaseModel`. Other attemps to completely clone the model with copy deepcopy etc have been also unsuccessful. I have got some success using `add_to_class` but I am not sure if it is a documented user level function and it modifies deeply the class, so I have not been able to produce two different, separated models.

The goal is be to be able to run a loop, say

```
for x in MyModel.objects.using('input').all():
    y = cast_to_AnnotatedModelInstance(x)
    y.pk = None
    y.summary = Foo(x)
    y.save(using='output')
```

without modifying the original model which is in a separate package. Ideally, I would prefer x to be objects of MyModel and then casting to AnnotatedModel and save them.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, what I am doing is to expand the model with add_to_class

```
from foo.bar.models import MyModel
MyModel.add_to_class('summary',m.TextField(null=True, blank=True))
```

then create the export database explicitly

```
with c['output'].schema_editor() as editor:
        editor.create_model(MyModel)
```

and then loop as in the question, with `using('input').defer("summary")` to access the original model of the application.

```
for x in MyModel.objects.using('input').defer("summary").all():
    x.pk = None
    x.summary = Foo(x)
    x.save(using='output')
```

Note that because of the add_to_class, the model tries to read the column summary even in the original database, fortunately it can be skipped using `defer`.